# Javascript - change text color in table when value is ... something

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a little problem, I'm a total beginner in Javascript, I've watched quite a few tutorials, but still can't find the answer. I have a simple HTML table where I change values frequently. I would like javascript to change the text color in td when the value of td is "X"

For example, when the value in td == "High" let the font color be red in that particular cell.

```
  <table id="something">
<tr>
  <th>City</th>
  <th>Min.</th>
  <th>Max.</th>
  <th>Delay</th>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>City 1</td>
  <td>$20</td>
  <td>$23</td>
  <td>Medium</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>City 2</td>
  <td>$20</td>
  <td>$23</td>
  <td>High</td>
</tr>
```

Update!

So yeah, I leave the simplest solution that works very well below:

```
elements = document.getElementsByTagName("td")
for (var i = elements.length; i--;) {
  if (elements[i].innerHTML === "High") {
    elements[i].style.color = "red";
  }
  if (elements[i].innerHTML === "Medium") {
    elements[i].style.color = "orange";    
  }
  if (elements[i].innerHTML === "Low") {
    elements[i].style.color = "green";  
  }
}
```

Comment: May be MutationObserver API would be helpful here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: You need a data structure for storing the colors and keywords. The exact structure depends on how much there are colors and how much there are keywords triggering the color change, and are the cells triggering different colors with the same keyword.

Comment: *Never* use `innerHTML`, it's not (properly) part of any standard and is horrible buggy as hell though you won't know it until you're 4 years of maintenance in to using it and need to remove it (note: you do *not* make money on maintenance). You should use `textContent` for both read and write functions to a node's text instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example changing the text color to red when the value of that field is High

```js
elements = document.getElementsByTagName("td")
for (var i = elements.length; i--;) {
  if (elements[i].innerHTML === "High") {
    elements[i].style.color = "red";
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="something">
  <tr>
    <th>City</th>
    <th>Min.</th>
    <th>Max.</th>
    <th>Delay</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>City 1</td>
    <td>$20</td>
    <td>$23</td>
    <td>Medium</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>City 2</td>
    <td>$20</td>
    <td>$23</td>
    <td>High</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, This is exactly what I meant and what I needed. I just need to understand the syntax, I know more or less what's going on. The most important thing is that it works!

Answer (score 1):

as @Prathamesh Koshti already mentioned, you can use mutation observer. Change a button at the bottom to randomly change `td`'s inner HTML to 'High':

```js
const observer = new MutationObserver(([{target: td}]) => {
  if (td.innerHTML === 'High') {
    td.classList.add('high');
  }
  else {
    td.classList.remove('high');
  }
});
const tds = document.querySelectorAll('td');

tds.forEach((td, ind) => {
  // add assistant CSS class
  td.classList.add(`index-${ind + 1}`);
  // add initial style if needed
  if (td.innerHTML === 'High') {
    td.classList.add('high');
  }
  observer.observe(td, {
    characterData: false, 
    childList: true, 
    attributes: false
  });
});

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',  () => {
  const randomTdIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * tds.length) + 1;
  const td = document.querySelector(`td.index-${randomTdIndex}`);
  if (td.innerHTML === 'High') {
    td.innerHTML = Date.now().toString().substr(-4);
  }
  else {
    td.innerHTML = 'High';
  }
})
```

```css
.high {
  color: red;
}

button {
  margin-top: 24px;
  border: solid 2px #378ad3;
}
```

```html
<table id="something">
<tr>
  <th>City</th>
  <th>Min.</th>
  <th>Max.</th>
  <th>Delay</th>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>City 1</td>
  <td>$20</td>
  <td>$23</td>
  <td>High</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>City 2</td>
  <td>$20</td>
  <td>$23</td>
  <td>High</td>
</tr>
</table>

<button>CHANGE RANDOM TD</button>
```

you will probably will want to reset 'red' color in the same manner if the HTML is not 'High'